# issue with bitmap image in android

Tags: java, android

I use some functions to show some images in my android app. Images read from server and all this works good. But I don't know why, my app show force close and the error is:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method **'int
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()'** on a null object reference

This is code that error is from there:

```
  Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
    int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;
```

Comment: `decodeFile` returns null when it was unable to load the given file. Your image file is invalid.

Comment: the files are valid i'm sure

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String) Returns null when could not be decoded.

Comment: try logging the value of `path` if its not a proper a path to the file that you are decoding (by proper I mean the path to the file from root like so `/mnt/sdcard0/...` ) then thats where your problem is

Comment: i get log of path and this is result: /data/data/com.mypack.name/cache/e714096070f59a72b6b0a82de8a29967

Comment: How does `path` get populated?

Comment: @weston  i uodate my answer so u can see ur answer

Comment: Still no idea where the value in `path` comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i used and default image for my problem. i put it in drawble folder and check if images not loaded from server it shows and no more error shows up!

UPDATE:

here is how i use this method:

```
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    if (source == null){
        source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.no_pic_feed);
    }
```